# How to only get from MongoDB documents that match a specific filter using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

My MongoDB Documents are like this:

```
"_id":"C\Users...\1.html"{
"data": Object[
        gambia:1
        estonia:1
        ...etc
        ]
}
```

I don't know if I wrote correctly the structure, so here you have a picture:

[image]

My problem is that I want to get from DB all Documents that match a specific word given. For example if the user enters "car" I need all the documents that in its data have the word car. But I couldn't find how to do it.

**What I tried?** I tried to get the first document that matches the word "gambia" which I know it exists in the first Document:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("motor");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("dictionary");
    String word = "gambia";
    Document myDoc = collection.find(Filters.eq("data", word)).first();
    System.out.println(myDoc);
```

But I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the mongodb function `$exists`.

This function tells you if a determinated field, is in your collection.

For example:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("dictionary");

String word = "gambia";

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("data." + word, new BasicDBObject(
            "$exists", true));

Document myDoc = collection.find(query);
System.out.println(myDoc);
```